# How to copy dirs with subdirs more easily?

Tags: java, directory, copy

I have to copy a dir somewhere else. I tried:

```
Files.copy(path1, path2, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Unfortunately, this just copies the dir - without its subdirs. I researched, of course, and found a possible solution to copy them recursively. Now I am wondering if there is no way, which is more simple? Or maybe a package which provides this recursive solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Commons IO has a useful [`FileUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) class that will do the heavy lifting for you:

```
FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File("/path/to/dir"), new File("/dest/to/copy/to"));
```